# How to count NFS clients connected to your NFS server?

Tags: server, filesystem, nfs

How to find out how many clients are connected to my nfs server and their IP or hostname?

Answer (score 2):

A quick method, which should work everywhere, is to list all connected sockets to the `nfs` port via `ss` on the server:

```
ss -a | grep nfs
```

There is also the [showmount](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/showmount.8.html) command:

```
showmount -a localhost
```

per manpage:

> showmount queries the mount daemon on a remote host for information about the state of the NFS  server  on  that machine.  With no options showmount lists the set of clients who are mounting from that host.  The output from showmount is designed to  appear  as  though  it were processed through ``sort -u''.

Note that there are some caveats to it:

> The  completeness and accuracy of the information that showmount displays varies according to the NFS server's implementation.
>
> Because showmount sorts and uniqs the output, it  is  impossible  to  determine  from  the output whether a client is mounting the same directory more than once.

So for example, if a client connects multiple times to the same mount, it will appear just once in the `showmount` output.
In this case with `ss -a` you should catch them.

Answer (score 0):

Since Linux kernel 5.3 you can use special directory called `/proc/fs/nfsd/clients`.

You can check Kernel version by `uname -r` command.